# model selection and stratified sampling in sklearn together

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, classification

I'm using scikit-learn to predict model using Kfold stratified sampling and KNeighborsClassifier together.

The dummy dataset is:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A' : [4,5,6,7,1,3,4,9,1,8], 'B' : [10,20,30,40,90,55,68,25,19,97],'C' : [100,50,30,89,54,23,13,67,93,84],'y' :[1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0]}).astype(np.float)
data1 = data.drop(['y'],axis = 1, inplace= False)

X = data1.as_matrix().astype(np.float)
X
y = data['y'].as_matrix().astype(np.int)
y
```

For Kfold stratified sampling, the code is:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold
def stratifiedkfold_cv(X, y, clf_class, shuffle=True, n_folds=2, **kwargs):
    stratifiedk_fold = StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds=n_folds, shuffle=shuffle)
    y_pred = y.copy()
    for train_index, test_index in stratifiedk_fold:
        X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
        y_train = y[train_index]
        clf = clf_class(**kwargs)
        clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
        y_pred[test_index] = clf.predict(X_test)
    return y_pred
```

i'm trying to fit the best possible sklearn.neighbors,KNeighborsClassifier by tuning the parameter:n_neighbors based on accuracy_score. The code is

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
k_range = range(1,31)
k_scores = []
for k in k_range:
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier
    y_pred = stratifiedkfold_cv(X, y,knn(n_neighbors = k))
    scores = accuracy_score(y, y_pred)
    k_scores.append(scores.mean())
print(k_scores)
```

But the error i'm getting is:
**----> 7 y_pred = stratifiedkfold_cv(X, y,knn(n_neighbors = k))
----> 7         clf = clf_class(**kwargs)
**TypeError: 'KNeighborsClassifier' object is not callable******

I believe i'm having some inconsistency with the function defined as stratifiedkfold_cv. But i'm unable to figure out how to modify it?

Comment: It would be easier for us if you could convert this to a [mcve]

Comment: do you want me to provide the value of X and y? will that be helpful?

Comment: You don't have to give your `X`, `y`. It's even easier for us if you can reproduce this error with a smaller toy dataset.

Comment: i have added a toy dataset and the error i get is the same as before

Comment: In `stratifiedkfold_cv` you request a class object, from which you construct your model. - But when you call it, you give `knn(n_neighbors = k)`, which is not a class, but already a fully initialized model.

Comment: What you probably want to to here is `y_pred = stratifiedkfold_cv(X, y,knn, n_neighbors=k)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def accuracy(y_true,y_pred):
    return np.mean(y_true == y_pred)    

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
    k_range = range(1,31)
    k_scores = []
    for k in k_range:
        knn = KNeighborsClassifier
        print accuracy(y, stratifiedkfold_cv(X,y,KNN,n_neighbors=k))
```